# Remove nonalphabet characters from a string

Tags: python

I have a string like `"lake1!"` and I want to remove non nonalphabet characters from this string.

How can I do that? Also, this is just an example but in general if have some string how can I remove nonalphabet characters from it?

For example: `"lake1!"` should return `"lake"` with `1` and `!` removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
word = 'lake1!'
new_word = ''
for char in word:
    if char.isalpha():
        new_word += char
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generator expression to filter out all non-ascii letters, the use `join` to create a string from that.

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> s = "lake1!"
>>> ''.join(i for i in s if i in ascii_lowercase)
'lake'
```

Or to include both lowercase and uppercase letters you can just check if the character `isalpha`

```
>>> s = "Some123?1Example"
>>> ''.join(i for i in s if i.isalpha())
'SomeExample'
```

Comment: FYI, there is a `islower` test method too; could use that the same way you use `isalpha` to simplify. Can even be shortened further to `''.join(filter(str.islower, s))` (in Py2, the `''.join` isn't even needed, since `filter` will return a `str` directly, simplifying further to `filter(str.islower, s)`).